# App script conversion of DOC to PDF ruins formatting

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-docs

I created a simple script to convert all DOC files in a directory to PDF files. The script assumes the folder in driver does not have any other files. It also recursively iterates over the sub-directories and convert DOC to PDF as expected. Here's the script:

```js
function convertDocToPdf(root) {
  if(!root) {
    root = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('conversion-test');
  }
  
  if(root.hasNext()) {
    var rootFolder = root.next();
    var files = rootFolder.getFiles();
    var folders = rootFolder.getFolders();
    
    while(files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      if(!file) continue ;
      convert(file, rootFolder);
   }
    while(folders.hasNext()) {
     convertDocToPdf(folders);
    }
  }
}


function convert(file, rootFolder) {
  var blob = file.getBlob();
  var tmp = Drive.Files.insert({}, blob, {convert:true});
  var id = tmp["id"];
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
  var text = doc.getBody().getText();
  var filename = file.getName();
  var name = filename.split('.')[0];
  rootFolder.createFile(name + '.pdf', text);
  Drive.Files.remove(id);
}
```

I tested this with simple files that only contains one line of text and it works. However, when I tried to convert a DOC file with images and other formatting (columns, tables) it removes all formatting and after download, the the file looks empty.

Are there any ways of preserving the format? What am I missing in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to convert Google Document files to the PDF files.
- In your script, you can retrieve the Google Document files from the folder.

#### Modification points:

- In the function of `convert(file, rootFolder)`, when `file` of `convert(file, rootFolder)` is Google Document, `blob` of `var blob = file.getBlob();` has already been the converted PDF format. But your script converts the PDF format to Google Document again and retrieve only the text data, and then, the text data is created as a PDF file. By this, the PDF file with only text data is created. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

In order to remove this issue and convert the Google Document to the PDF file, I would like to modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, I modified `convert`.

```
function convert(file, rootFolder) {
  if (file.getMimeType() != MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS) return;
  var blob = file.getBlob();
  var filename = file.getName();
  var name = filename.split('.')[0];  
  rootFolder.createFile(blob.setName(name + '.pdf'));
}
```

#### Note:

- In this case, the Google Document is converted to the PDF format with `file.getBlob()`. But when you want to use the Drive API for this, you can also use the following script. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)

  - From

    ```
      var blob = file.getBlob();
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var url = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${file.getId()}/export?mimeType=${MimeType.PDF}`;
      var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`}}).getBlob();
    ```

#### Reference:

- [getBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getblob)